# Accessing the runtime type of a polymorphic object by switch and static_cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, events, event-handling, polymorphism

I'd like to use an asynchronous event pattern to decouple my program. I would also like to keep the base event class oblivious of the implementations, to have the widest freedom of passing whatever I like by the event. So using a static_cast inside a switch seems to me a simple and possibly safe solution:

```
enum class EventType
{
    None,
    EventA,
    EventB
};

class BaseEvent
{
    public:
        BaseEvent(EventType t = EventType::None) : type(t) { }
        virtual ~BaseEvent() {}
        auto get_type() { return type; }
    private:
        EventType type;

    // Oblivious and clean interface
};

class EventA : public BaseEvent
{
    public:
        EventA() : BaseEvent(EventType::EventA) { }

    // ... whatever I like
};
class EventB : public BaseEvent
{
    public:
        EventB() : BaseEvent(EventType::EventB) { }

    // ... whatever I like
};

void handle_event(BaseEvent* pe)
{
    switch (pe->get_type())
    {
        case EventType::EventA:
        {
            EventA* original_a = static_cast<EventA*>(pe);

            // In this case I know what is "pe" and what 
            // operations and data I can access and use.

            break;
        }
        case EventType::EventB:
        {
            EventB* original_b = static_cast<EventB*>(pe);

            //...

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm also aware that using a static_cast poses some risk, since it breaks type checking. From my idealistic point of view it doesn't seem so dangerous in this case, even for future maintainability. One must only check that the line

```
case EventType::EventA:
```

is consistent with the following line

```
EventA* original_a = static_cast<EventA*>(pe);
```

I know that in theory this could seem less than a problem, but the practice is really different. Could this solution work for a large project? Are there any better strategies to accomplish this pattern?

I know that I could use an array or vector of std::variant in the base class, but it appears quite limiting about the possible implementations of the derived events. I could also use a map to store the parameter names and their values, but it seems quite slower and memory unfriendly and likewise limiting about possible types of parameters.

Alternatively I could also use a `dynamic_cast` although has its overhead, but maybe it repays the cost increasing the maintainability.

## EDIT

In the effort to be concise I forgot to mention some important details about the question:

- The events have to be enqueued in a container polymorphically, so I think that CRTP it's not feasible.
- The context is a real-time agent-based simulation (a videogame), where I have a main loop iterating through the events. The events can be fired anywhere in each iteration. They'll be processed by specific handlers in the following iteration(s).

  ```
  std::queue<BaseEvent*> past_events;

  int main()
  {
      while (true)
      {
          while (!past_events.empty())
          {
              handle_event(past_events.front());

              //handle_event2(...)
              //handle_event3(...)
              //...

              past_events.pop();
          }

          // New events are fired...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Take a look at the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) if you want to have _static polymorphism_.

Comment: Also note that such constructs usually are a clear sign of a flawed design.

Comment: This is a widely accepted practice (even back in C code). It even has some library routines. See [LLVM-style RTTI](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the suggestion. I've added more details about the context. I think that using CRTP a derived of `BaseEvent` couldn't be stored in a container. Is it right?

Comment: @VTT Thanks I've read the article only now. This makes me feel more confident about the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysis of your design

At first sight, one could think that this is suboptimal design, because you don't use polymorphism to let the event do the proper action itself instead of letting the event handler switch and cast.  But when reading your arguments another picture emerges:

You decided to put the logic for handling the events in the event handler on purpose.  This allows you to decouple the processing of an event from the event itself. In other words different event handlers could have a completely different behavior for the same event (depending on context, on event receiver, on application, etc...), just as every windows application has some event loop and reacts on the same events in a totally different manner.

So you deliberately chose not to put the behavior in the event, and therefore you can't use polymorphism in the event.  Not knowing the context, it is difficult to advise another approach.

### Consequences

Since you have defined the logic to get the event type in the base class, you can assume that you know sufficiently well its type and go for a `static_cast`.  But...

#### Risk number 1

There is however a serious risk that one day a new event type is created  with the wrong event type (copy and paste, typo, etc...).  This might lead to UB.

**Risk mitigation**:

- use a `dynamic_cast` to intercept such inconsistencies in each event handler at run time. Note that maintainers could forget this, so this is risk reduction and not risk prevention
- or foresee a test suite that creates all the event types and does the `dynamic_cast` consistency check at build time.

#### Risk number 2

You may have some unintended copy of an event (copy constructor or assignment), with or without slicing, that accidentally overwrites the real type of the event (e.g. `if (*eventA=*eventB) /* ouch!! == */`).

**Risk mitigation**: delete the copy constructor and assignment from the base event class to prevent such accidents.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I've edited the question adding more details about the context. Do you think it's still a feasible pattern (a part the risks you highlighted)?

Comment: @Tarquiscani I see that in your main loop you have several event handlers, which could justify your design.  A multiple dispatch (i.e. polymorphism depends on event handler and event) would require a coupling between the handlers and event and have similar drawbacks when adding new event types.  Other alternatives (e.g.table driven dispatch) would not be less error prone to maintain.  So yes, I think my analysis is still valid.  And yes, I highly recommend the mitigation measures proposed.